# How to retrieve data from JSon file using String request

Tags: android, json

[image]

How to get the traslated Text?

```
 JsonObject json = new JsonObject(response);
 JsonObject data = json.getJsonObject("data").getString("translations").getString("translated Text");
```

Comment: `translations` is a JsonArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translations` is a JsonArray, so you must get it as an array.

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(response);
JsonObject data = json.getJsonObject("data");
JsonArray transalations = data.getJsonArray("transalations");
String translatedText = transalations.getJsonObject(0).getString("translatedText");
```